# How to get same value from array of objects using javaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays, my aim is to filter the second array `arr2` by the first array `arr1`, and get only matched values where `prid` is the same as `arr2` id, results should be `let filtred = [ {name:'kiwi', color:'red', id:12123},{name:'kiwi', color:'red', id:12123}]`, how i can ichieve this using `filter`?

```js
let arr1 = [
  {prid:12123},
  {prid:12124}
]

let arr2 = [
  {name:'kiwi', color:'red', id:12123},
  {name:'kiwi2', color:'blue',id:12129},
  {name:'kiwi3', color:'green',id:12124}
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Please note:** According to your requirement your expected output is not correct:*

You can try using [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) inside [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) by matching the respective property value (`prid` of `arr1` with `id` of `arr2`).

```js
let arr1 = [
  {prid:12123},
  {prid:12124}
]

let arr2 = [
  {name:'kiwi', color:'red', id:12123},
  {name:'kiwi2', color:'blue',id:12129},
  {name:'kiwi3', color:'green',id:12124}
]

let filtred = arr2.filter(i => arr1.some(j => j.prid == i.id))
console.log(filtred);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) which allows to create another array with different structure

```js
let arr1 = [
  {prid:12123},
  {prid:12124}
]

let arr2 = [
  {name:'kiwi', color:'red', id:12123},
  {name:'kiwi2', color:'blue',id:12129},
  {name:'kiwi3', color:'green',id:12124}
]

let results = arr2.reduce((accumulator, currentItem) =>{
  let itemExists = arr1.findIndex(item => item.prid === currentItem.id);
  return itemExists !== -1? accumulator.concat(currentItem): accumulator;
}, []);

console.log(results);
```